# copy of an array JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have some objects:

```
var obj1 = new Obj1(),
    obj2 = new Obj2(),
    ...
```

and two arrays:

```
objecs.push(obj1, obj2,...);
defaultObjects.push(obj1, obj2, ...);
```

During the game loop `objects` array changes, but `defaultObjects` does not.
When the game needs to be restarted, I need to make `objects` equal to `defaultObjects` (just like it was in the beginning).
if I do this:

`objects = defaultObjects.slice(0)`

does it mean that `objects[0]` and `defaultObjects[0]` are now pointing at the same object `obj1`, but there is no connection between `objects` and `defaultObjects` so I get what I need?

Comment: You will be able to restart the game once though.

Comment: @Alexander, why? `defaultObjects` is static so I can restart it many times.

Comment: Oh nevermind, I thought you were gonna modify the `objX`s themselves.

Comment: Yes, but they get default props before each restarting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is correct. [`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) will return you a new array.
However, as you have mentioned, array elements will still be referring to the same objects. I.e. changing any object from one array will lead to its change in another.